# Ruby hash permutation

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, permutation, ruby-1.9

Is there any quick way to get a (random) permutation of a given hash? For example with arrays I can use the [sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sample) method as in

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :031 > a = (1..5).to_a
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :032 > a.sample(a.length)
 => [3, 5, 1, 2, 4]
```

For hashes I can use the same method on hash keys and build a new hash with

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :036 > h = { 1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c' }
 => {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c"} 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :037 > h.keys.sample(h.length).inject({}) { |h2, k| h2[k] = h[k]; h2 }
 => {3=>"c", 2=>"b", 1=>"a"}
```

but this is so ugly. Is there any 'sample' method for hashes which can avoid all that code?

**Update** As pointed out by @Michael Kohl in comments, this question is meaningful only for ruby 1.9.x. Since in 1.8.x Hash are unordered there is no way to do that.

Comment: What's the point of this? In 1.8 hashes are unordered and in 1.9 ordered by insertion order.

Comment: @Michael: Looks like he's using 1.9 so shuffling a Hash makes some sense since `h.each` does have a well defined order.

Comment: @MichaelKohl it's just a curiosity. Furthermore even with 1.8 unordered hashes calling that method will return a different order each time instead of the deterministic and fixed order. Think about it as a shuffle for the hash class.

Comment: @Fabio have you tested? I thought the accepted answer would not have any effect in ruby 1.8.6 .

Comment: @steenslag I've tested both methods in 1.9.2 and they work. However none of them works in 1.8.x, I've just tried using rvm with `1.8.7-p334`. Sample method is not available in 1.8.x, shuffle works but, as you say, it has no effect when building the new Hash.

Comment: @muistooshort: Sure, I wrote that in my comment. But since hashes are usually looked up by key... Anyway, intelectual curiosity is at least as good an argument as many others :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A slight refinement of mu is too short's answer:

```
h = Hash[h.to_a.shuffle]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add a [`to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-to_a) and [`Hash[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) to your array version to get a Hash version:

```
h = Hash[h.to_a.sample(h.length)]
```

For example:

```
>> h = { 1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c' }
=> {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c"}
>> h = Hash[h.to_a.sample(h.length)]
=> {2=>"b", 1=>"a", 3=>"c"}
```

Comment: @steenslag: That looks like an answer (and a good one), you should put it down as such.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to shuffle or do you just need a way to access/iterate on a random key ?

Otherwise, a maybe less expensive solution would be to shuffle the hash keys and access your items based on the permutation of those hash keys

```
h = your_hash
shuffled_hash_keys = hash.keys.shuffle

shuffled_hash_keys.each do |key|
  # do something with h[key]
end
```

I believe (but would need a proof with a benchmark) that this avoids the need/cost to build a brand new hash and is probably more efficient if you have big hashes (you only need to pay the cost of an array permutation)